# How would I make sure and record that the image uploaded is by the user logged in?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I'm currently using Laravel auth to register/login with no problems.  I've set up a file upload component using React.js where the user can upload an image.  I want that image to be uploaded and file name sent to the database in the `filename` column with whatever user is logged in.

I've created a model via `php artisan make:model Fileupload -m` but kind of lost as to what to put in there since I'm kind of new to backend concepts.

This is the tutorial I'm following: https://appdividend.com/2018/03/23/react-js-laravel-file-upload-tutorial/

In Layman's terms, I want the file name that's been sent to the DB to be associated with the user who did the uploading.  I have some code below.  What am I doing wrong and how can I rectify this?

Here's `create_users_table.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Here's `create_fileuploads_table`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Here's `FileuploadController.php`:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Fileupload;


class FileuploadController extends Controller
}

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->get('file'))
        {
            $image = $request->get('file');
            $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];
            \Image::make($request->get('file'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);
        }
        $fileupload = new Fileupload();
        $fileupload->filename=$name;
        $fileupload->save();
        return response()->json('Successfully added');
    }


}
```

Here's `FileUpload.php` (model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fileupload extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Here's my JS component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Wall extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            image: ''
        };

        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.image);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if(!files.length) {
            return;
        }
        this.createImage(files[0]);
    }

    createImage(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                image: e.target.result
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    fileUpload(image){
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/fileupload';
        const formData = {file: this.state.image};
        return  axios.post(url, formData)
            .then(response => console.log(response));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>File Upload</h1>
                <input type="file" />
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Wall;
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking to this statement:

> In Layman's terms, I want the file name that's been sent to the DB to be associated with the user who did the uploading.

To do this you should:

1. Add a `user_id` column to the `fileuploads` table.

*You will need to make a new migration to add the column if the table has already been migrated.*

```php
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```

2. Create a relationship between the two tables.

**User.php**

```php
public function fileuploads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Fileupload::class);
}
```

**Fileupload.php**

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

3. Save using the relationship.

**FileuploadController.php**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->get('file'))
    {
        $image = $request->get('file');
        $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];
        \Image::make($request->get('file'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);
    }

    // save the file upload with association to the authorized user
    auth()->user()->fileuploads()->save(new Fileupload([
        filename => $name,
    ]));    

    return response()->json('Successfully added');
}
```

Comment: ah ok, I think I understand that flow a bit better now. Even though I tried this, It's still not sending anything to the DB. I even ran `php artisan migrate`   after making changes to the table but I get a message in the console saying `Nothing to migrate.`. Very strange.  Also, I think you meant for the last block of code to go into `FileuploadController.php`? :)

Comment: You can't edit an existing migration once it's been run.  You'll need to create a new migration for the update — `php artisan make:migration add_user_id_to_fileuploads_table --table=fileuploads`.  Yes, the code for the last part was copied from `FileuploadController.php` above.  I have added the filename to the answer for reference.